# CustomAttributes not behaving as expected

Tags: c#

I would expect there to be three lines of output from this code, but there are none:

```
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Property )]
public class FieldAttribute : System.Attribute
{
  public String FieldName
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class Host
{

  [Field]
  public String FieldOne
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Field(FieldName="Foo")]
  public String FieldTwo
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [FieldAttribute]
  public String FieldThree
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public String FieldFour
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}


class Program
{
  static void Main( string[] args )
  {
    Type t = typeof(Host);
    foreach ( Object att in t.GetCustomAttributes( typeof(FieldAttribute), true ) )
    {
      Console.WriteLine( att.ToString() );
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing soemthing obvious?

Andrew

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281972/c-reflection-how-to-get-a-list-of-properties-with-a-given-attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t.GetCustomAttributes` returns the attributes declared on the class itself.

You need to loop through `t.GetProperties()` and call `GetCustomAttributes` on the individual `PropertyInfo`s.

Comment: Can property attribute be applied to a method? Should not `GetProperties` overload be used instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in the Main method:

```
Type t = typeof(Host);
foreach(var prop in t.GetProperties())
{
    var attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldAttribute), true);
    foreach(var attr in attrs)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", prop.Name, attr.ToString());
}
```