# Get all properties which marked certain attribute

Tags: c#, reflection

I have class and properties in there. Some properties can be marked attribute (it's my `LocalizedDisplayName` inherits from `DisplayNameAttribute`).
This is method for get all properties of class:

```
private void FillAttribute()
{
    Type type = typeof (NormDoc);
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to add properties of class in the listbox which marked `LocalizedDisplayName` and display value of attribute in the listbox. How can I do this?

**EDIT**
This is LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute:

```
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
    {
        public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceId)
            : base(GetMessageFromResource(resourceId))
        { }

        private static string GetMessageFromResource(string resourceId)
        {
            var test =Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager("EArchive.Data.Resources.DataResource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            return manager.GetString(resourceId);
        }
    }
```

I want to get string from resource file.
Thanks.

Comment: What is "value of attribute"?  Attributes are classes, and could have a *lot* of "values" (properties/fields).  Maybe you're talking about the result from `ToString()`?  Can you edit your question to add some code for the custom attributes you're applying, and specify which data you want off it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a list of properties with a given attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281972/how-to-get-a-list-of-properties-with-a-given-attribute)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use [`IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined.aspx):

```
var properties = type.GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute), false));
```

To get the values themselves, you'd use:

```
var attributes = (LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute[]) 
      prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute), false);
```

Comment: +1; Nit-pick: I would specify `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>` here :)  Helpful if the person seeing this answer isn't familiar with Linq or Reflections.