# How identify a primary key parameter from an ASP NET MVC Model object based on annotation [key] tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model, key

Given this model class

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    public uint MyObjectId { get; set; }
    public long Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

How to programmatically identify the primary key parameter based on the `[Key]` annotation?

In this case it would be `MyObjectId`

Comment: You can use reflection.  Take a look at this answer from a similar question :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7305854/6347013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    public uint MyObjectId { get; set; }
    public long Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()
      .Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(KeyAttribute), false));
}
```