# C# NET Looping over object properties stored in List

Tags: c#, .net, excel, reflection, xlsx

At the moment I'm working on funcionality that involves exporting and importing data to Xlsx file. Here's what I want to do: I want to have an attribute I can put above a property like this.

```
public class MyClass
{
   [XlsxColumn("Column 1")]
   public string myProperty1 { get; set; }
   public int myProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

So far I don't have problems, but then I want to "store references"  to properties marked with the XlsxColumn attribute. I'm using reflection 
to store properties data in List

```
var propsList = MyClass.GetProperties().Where(
   prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(XlsxColumn)));
```

I have a list with all properties marked with XlsxColumn (only myProperty1 in this example).

EDIT: The problem is I don't know how to loop over properties in MyClass, but only  properties with XlsxColumn attribute (so all PropertyInfo objects stored in propsList variable), without resorting to reflection with each object saved to Xlsx file.

I'm restricted to .NET 4.0.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the problem?  What is your question?  Please be more precise.

Comment: Rephrased my post.

Comment: I think what you are doing is close https://stackoverflow.com/a/7305854/7927820

Answer (score 1):

`MyClass.GetProperties()` does not work because you have to get the type of the class to invoke the [GetProperties method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.7.2). Otherwise you are invoking a static method called GetProperties defined in the MyClass class.

```
var propsList = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().Where(
                prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(XlsxColumnAttribute), false)).ToList();
```

If you just want the names (`IList<string>`):

```
var propsList = typeof(Excel).GetProperties().Where(
                prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(XlsxColumnAttribute), false))
                .Select(prop=> prop.Name)
                .ToList();
```

to use `.Where` you have to include `System.Linq`

Answer (score 0):

I must say that I am not sure if this is the solution you are looking for. Because I could not quite make out what your question is. Well I have tried to provide an answer as much as I could figure out.

I went for a static class for `CachingPropetyProvider` but you can go for an instance class and use a dependency injection library and use it as a `Singleton` too. Moreover, I have written extensive comments so It is as self explanatory as possible.

Let us define MyClass. I also deliberately changed it a little bit.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XlsxColumn("Column 1")]
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }

    [XlsxColumn("Column 2")]
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

I also defined a `MetaInfo` class to hold the cached information.

```
public class MetaInfo {

    /// <summary>
    /// Immutable class for holding PropertyInfo and XlsxColumn info.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info">PropertyInfo</param>
    /// <param name="attr">XlsxColumn</param>
    public MetaInfo(PropertyInfo info, XlsxColumn attr) {
        PropertyInfo = info;
        Attribute = attr;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// PropertyInfo. You may want to access the value inside the property.
    /// </summary>
    public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attribute. You may want to access information hold inside the attribute.
    /// </summary>
    public XlsxColumn Attribute { get; }
}
```

And lastly the main guy. This guy is responsible for providing all the data about classes

```
public class CachingPropProvider {

/// <summary>
/// Holds the meta information for each type.
/// </summary>
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<MetaInfo>> TypeCache;

/// <summary>
/// Static constructor is guaranteed to run only once.
/// </summary>
static CachingPropProvider() {
    //Initialize the cache.
    TypeCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<MetaInfo>>();
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the MetaInfo for the given type. Since We use ConcurrentDictionary it is thread safe.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type parameter</typeparam>
public static IEnumerable<MetaInfo> GetCachedStuff<T>() {
    //If Type exists in the TypeCache, return the cached value
    return TypeCache.GetOrAdd(typeof(T),Factory);
}

/// <summary>
/// Factory method to use to extract MetaInfo when Cache is not hit.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">Type to extract info from</param>
/// <returns>A list of MetaInfo. An empty List, if no property has XlsxColumn attrbiute</returns>
private static List<MetaInfo> Factory(Type @type) {
    //If Type does not exist in the TypeCahce runs Extractor
    //Method to extract metainfo for the given type
    return @type.GetProperties().Aggregate(new List<MetaInfo>(), Extractor);
}

/// <summary>
/// Extracts MetaInfo from the given property info then saves it into the list.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="seedList">List to save metainfo into</param>
/// <param name="propertyInfo">PropertyInfo to try to extract info from</param>
/// <returns>List of MetaInfo</returns>
private static List<MetaInfo> Extractor(List<MetaInfo> seedList,PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
    //Gets Attribute
    var customattribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<XlsxColumn>();

    //If custom attribute is not null, it means it is defined
    if (customattribute != null)
    {
        //Extract then add it into seed list
        seedList.Add(new MetaInfo(propertyInfo, customattribute));
    }
    //Return :)
    return seedList;
}

}
```

Finally let us see how to use the solution. It is pretty straightforward actually.

```
//Has 2 values inside
var info = CachingPropProvider.GetCachedStuff<MyClass>();
```