# How can I get the values of all fields with a given attribute in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a `struct` with fields I want to make into a human-readable list. I created a `DisplayName` attribute that holds the string I want to appear in the final list:

```cs
public struct ColumnMeta {
 [DisplayName("Coords.")]
 public Vec2i Location;

 [DisplayName("Age")]
 public TimeSpan ChunkAge;

 public byte ChunkSize;
}
```

I can easily print all of the names via

```cs
var fields = typeof(ColumnMeta).GetFields();
foreach (var f in fields) {
 foreach (Attribute att in f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute))) {
  DisplayNameAttribute dnAtt = (DisplayNameAttribute) att;
  Console.WriteLine(dnAtt.name);
 }
}
```

This prints `Coords.` and `Age` as it should.

However, if I have an instance of `ColumnMeta`, how can I iterate over fields that have the `DisplayName` attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305787/get-all-properties-which-marked-certain-attribute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2281972