# How to detect in code if property is decorated with HiddenInput

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view where I need to detect if a property is decorated with hidden input.

My property is defined as:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public string UserName{ get; set; }
```

My attempt so far has been:

```
var column.Member = "UserName";

if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.HideSurroundingHtml == true && 
      ViewData.Values.Contains(column.Member))
{                          
  column.Visible = false;
}
```

I have read that I might be able to use "HideSurroundingHtml" to determine if the property should not be displayed.

Any ideas how to detect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem is as follows:

I have created html helper that gives me array of names with properties that has been decorated with the "HiddenInput" attribute.

```
   public static string[] GetListOfHiddenPropertiesFor<T>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        {
            Type t = typeof(T);
            var propertyInfos = t.GetProperties()
                                .Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(HiddenInputAttribute)))
                                .Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
            return propertyInfos;
        }
```

this is all i needed

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to see if a specific property has an attribute.

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281972/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-a-list-of-properties-with-a-given-attribute).

In the various answers a user also [posted a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282190/394028) to create an extension method to check if a property has a specific attribute or not. Hope it helps