# Get All properties that has a custom attribute with specific values

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, attributes, data-annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a list of properties with a given attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281972/how-to-get-a-list-of-properties-with-a-given-attribute)

I have a custom class like this

```
public class ClassWithCustomAttributecs
{
    [UseInReporte(Use=true)]
    public int F1 { get; set; }

    public string F2 { get; set; }

    public bool F3 { get; set; }

    public string F4 { get; set; }
}
```

I have a custom attribute `UseInReporte`:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property ,AllowMultiple = true)]
public class UseInReporte : System.Attribute
{
    public bool Use;

    public UseInReporte()
    {
        Use = false;
    }
}
```

No I want to get All properties that has `[UseInReporte(Use=true)]` how I can do this using reflection?

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
List<PropertyInfo> result =
    typeof(ClassWithCustomAttributecs)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(
        p =>
            p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UseInReporte), true)
            .Where(ca => ((UseInReporte)ca).Use)
            .Any()
        )
    .ToList();
```

Of course `typeof(ClassWithCustomAttributecs)` should be replaced with an actual object you are dealing with.

Comment: Not sure how this handles `[UseInReporte(Use=true)]`

Comment: thanks dear friend. How I can get properties wihich `Use == true` ?

Comment: @JonB, good point, thanks. Updated the answer

Comment: @Kerezo, please see the updated version.

Comment: Instead of `.Count() >= 1` i would take `.Any()`.

Comment: @Kerezo, are you expected to obtain properties with attribute of exact type UseInReporte, or any of its subclass?