# How to retrieve all fields with particular attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form translator that loops through a page's control collection and translates any text which has a new phrase for the current culture stored in the database. But it turns out this is not enough. I also need to be able to translate strings stored in fields. For this purpose, I want to annotate these strings with a new custom attribute called Localizable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject.Business.BusinessHelp
{
    public class Localizable : Attribute
    {

    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
[Localizable]
public string articles = "articles";
[Localizable]
public string summary = "summary";
```

(amidst many fields which aren't Localizable, of course)

So how do I retrieve a list of these at runtime, using Page or Page.Form?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281972/how-to-get-a-list-of-properties-with-a-given-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using fields, so it would be like this:

```
 using System.Reflection;
 Type outputType = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly");
 IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = outputType.GetFields().Where(
       p => p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Localizable)) != null);
```

So the `fields` enumeration contains only collection of `FieldInfo` that have your `Localizable` attribute. If you would use properties, you will need to use `GetProperties()` instead of `GetFields()`.

Then as soon as you want to modify fields with `Localizable` attribute you can do something like this:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
fields.First(x=>x.Name == "articles").SetValue(mc, "Das ist ein Artikel.");
```

Comment: I'm using a variant of this now, and it seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, wait. I can now retrieve the appropriate fields. But how do I update their values with the translated phrases?

Comment: `FieldInfo` has `SetValue` method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get all the fields by looking up the attribute. You can, however, loop through all the fields and check if each one has the attribute.

```
foreach(FieldInfo f in typeof(SomeClass).GetFields()){
    if (f.GetCustomAttributes().Any(t=>t is LocalizableAttribute)) {
        var name = f.Name; //this is how you get the field name
        ....
    }
}
```